# Get last element on Json without name

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json converted in string `JSON.stringify(result)` now i need to get the last value EMAIL:

```
["VALUEA","VALUEB","VALUEC","VALUED","EMAIL"]
```

I have tried with:

```
var str = JSON.stringify(result);
var emaillsegna = str.split(/[\s,]+/);
emaillsegna[emaillsegna.length-1]
```

But this return value with ] ex: "info@asdasda.com]"

Have any suggestion? If is not necessary im not convert to string!

How to get any value with a json if this value not have a tipicaly name NAME:VALUE?

Comment: If it's json why not just use `str.EMAIL`? If you do `var str = JSON.parse(result)` you can get `str.EMAIL` as a value

Comment: Ummm, `result[result.length-1]` unless I'm missing something

Comment: because the json is ["DATA1","DATA2","DATA3","DATA4","info@adada.COM"]

Comment: Oh it doesn't have an index? Is it always the same amount of values?

Comment: yes always an email =)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, `str` is a string, the JSON text. `result` is an array (by looking at the resulting JSON text). Even if it was the other way around, it is an array, `str.EMAIL` wouldn't work as there is no key `EMAIL`

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes I understand now that there is no key

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks you =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the json as an array and then take the last element if I understand correctly:

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "EMAIL"];
var js = JSON.stringify(a);
console.log(js);

var a1 = JSON.parse(js);
console.log(a1[a1.length-1]);
```

Comment: I just resolved with result[result.length-1] from suggestion of Patrick =)

Comment: Thanks in any case =)

Comment: @user3477026 No problems!